# Adobe Illustrator - How do I separate the dot from a lower case "i"?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

How do I separate the dot from a lower case "i" so I can re-color just the dot?
I want the straight part black and the dot red.

Answer (score 11):

`Type > Create Outlines` From the menu. Text will no longer be editable as live text though.

---

Although really.. I'd just draw a secondary shape to cover the dot. Then group it with the text.

---

Or you could utilize the **Appearance Panel** to create a covering shape...

[image]

When the fill is changed to white, it makes the dot of the i essentially disappear. And you can alter the fill color to match a colored background if necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Type your text and add a `period` (aka the dot) right after the `i`. Color the dot red. Open the character panel, select the dot and adjust the baseline shift. Place the cursor between the `i` and the dot but ensure nothing is selected. Apply a negative kern value until the dot covers the dot in the `i` glyph. Perhaps tweak the size of the dot to ensure it covers what you need it to cover.

In the image below, which shows the kerning setting, the actual text is `Li.ght`

[image]

Comment: Interesting method.

Comment: (the period and the dot on the `i` are not always a match in typefaces)

Comment: wow, that's even clunkier than mine. :)

Comment: eh...it works :)

Answer (score 4):

Some fonts may actually have a dotless-i glyph: ı

On Windows, try <kbd>Alt 0305</kbd>  to type it (or, I suppose, just copy-paste from my answer).

This is, to the best of my knowledge, a Turkish glyph, though many fonts support it for use in ligatures. Check out [the Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I) on it. I think this is the easiest way to accomplish what you want, since you can then replace the tittle with whatever you like without masking or losing your editability.

I'd say this is the most portable and least clunky method, provided your font has this glyph. And all good fonts ought to.

**[EDIT]** Sorry for the repeat edit, but I don't have enough rep yet to comment. This method is beneficial over Lauren Ipsum's (sorry Lauren, though you've got a baller username!) because it doesn't require an intermediate blocking layer, and text-reflow is easy because you're only moving the tittle shape, which can, of course, be grouped to the text as well.

Comment: If the font does have a tittleless i, this would be a great way to go, I agree. And thanks for the compliment on my name. :)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend making a copy of your text, that way if you do not prefer the change or want to kern it or treat it like live text that way you still can. Also a shortcut to create outlines is <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (O not 0). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit clunky, but if you want to keep the **i** live:

- Lock the layer with the text.
- Make a new layer. Draw a circle the exact shape of the tittle (that's
  the real name) and color it red. (Alternatively, duplicate the **i** onto a new layer, color it red, covert it to outlines, and delete just the stroke while keeping the tittle.)
- To make sure the black doesn't show through, create a third layer
  between the text and the red tittle. Draw a small white box or circle
  over the black tittle to block it out.
- Unlock the text layer and group all your layers together so that if you move the live text, you
  move your tittle and the tittle-blocker.

Answer (score 2):

`Type > Create Outlines` then if you have the letter in a word you should go in isolate mode or ungroup the word (<kbd>Ctrl+Shif+G</kbd>)

Comment: welcome to GD but isnt this a duplicate answer to Scott's at the top?

Comment: Well I thought he didn't mention to ungroup it.. but if it's a duplicate then my answer can be deleted. But I thought this answer was a bit more detailed

Answer (score 1):

Once you've entered your type using the `type tool`, you will want to create a duplicate of this type and move it to the pasteboard (the dark space around your artboard).  The smartest way to create a duplicate is with the shortcut <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> + <kbd>drag</kbd> using the `selection tool`.  Duplicating and "sidelining" your work is just a best practice of "saving your progress" so you can easily revert back to earlier versions.

Now with one of your two copies of the type, press <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to do what's called "creating outlines."  Your type should now be populated with anchor points along the edges.  Using the `direct selection tool`, simply click inside the tittle (the dot of the "i") and in the color window choose your desired red.  Be careful to not click on a path or an anchor point when you intend on clicking the tittle.

Generally speaking you will want to reserve the step of creating outlines for near the end of your typesetting.  Once you perform this step you will be unable to adjust the typeface, kerning, leading, and other features of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight your "i" and press option + shift + B

Comment: You should probably explain that this is an OSX shortcut (and nothing to do with Illustrator) and a shortcut for the dotless "i" which is font dependent and doesn't actually need you to highlight an "i"

Answer (score 0):

- Select the `I`.
- Right-click and select *release compound path*.
- Then select just the dot.